# How do you factor $x^3-3x^2-4x+12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you factor $x^3-3x^2-4x+12$ ?

I tried to factor $x(x^2-3x-4) + 12$ instead and I got

$x(x-4)(x+1)+12$ but apparently this can be factored further.

Comment: You can start by grouping the 1st two terms and the last two terms.

Comment: Hint: $x^3 - 3x^2 = (x-3)x^2$ and $4x -12 = 4(x-3)$

Comment: You either need to solve cubical equation and use roots to write it as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, or start guessing to find at least one integer root, if there are any.

Comment: @user84413: or you could group the first and third terms and the second and fourth terms

Comment: See [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: I noted that plugging in $x=2$ gives $0$. Divide by $x-2$ and the rest should be easy.

Answer (score 4):

THanks for the hints. I think I got it.

$(x+2)(x-2)(x-3)$

Comment: You can do a bit more.

Comment: Ok, now it should be completely factored.

Comment: Yup, it's fully factored now